# c# webcam controls?

Tags: c#, webcam, directshow.net

I am looking to put a camera on top of a my lab in the process of being built and stream it to a website.

How can I be doing  this with only c# ? How to get stream of video & send it live on server PC from there he can take instant photos?

Answer (score 1):

Modern web cameras would supports WIA and DirectShow. WIA has a scripting interface which is more friendly to C#, however it is designed for cameras and scanners and is not that fast for streaming. But if you just need to push the image to a server, you don't need to write code, kist use Windows Media Encoder to push to a Windows Media Server's publishing point. You can then get image from the server's publishing point using DirectShow or Windows Media Format SDK. None of these are easy in C# though, you are better off using COM class libraries like ATL for extensive COM programming like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to write this in C#, I've had a lot of success with [Egmu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Capturing images is very straightforward - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765107/how-to-display-webcam-images-captured-with-emgu/1666828#1666828). After that, it'd be FTP to the server as usual.

I'm curious about Sheng Jiang's Media Encoder solution though. Let me know how you get on.