# best C# library for getting IP Camera stream?

Tags: c#

I found there's quite a lot of IP Camera libraries for C# on the net. In case you have worked with any of them, which seem to be the best?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/) is an open source C# wrapper for Open-CV which is a robust open source library for image processing and more. It has some out of the box webcam image capturing [examples](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Capture_in_7_lines_of_code) using only seven lines of code.

The web cam part look like it was address in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765107/how-to-display-webcam-images-captured-with-emgu).

Getting the camera stream through  (httprequest)webrequest is not a huge deal. Most cameras will send the video back in an MJPEG stream. The stream is just a multi-part message that is broken up by a delimiter, specified in the head section of the response, and two carriage returns. The data inbetween the delimiters are JPEG images which you can feed into the wrapper for the CV library.

Comment: Does Emgu support IP cams? It's great for USB-connected cameras, but I'm not so sure about net-connected jobbies.