# EmguCV: BitmapSource isn't updated on GUI after PropertyChanged Event:

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, emgucv

I want to simply capture and display a camera picture on my view, updated every second. However the image container, which is bound to my Bitmapsource `CurrentFrame`stays blank during runtime. 
This is my code so far (mostly adopted from [an answer of another thread with similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765107/how-to-display-webcam-images-captured-with-emgu):

```
public class CameraViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public CameraViewModel()
    {
        StartVideo();
    }

    private DispatcherTimer Timer { get; set; }

    private VideoCapture Capture { get; set; }

    private BitmapSource currentFrame;
    public BitmapSource CurrentFrame
    {
        get { return currentFrame; }
        set
        {
            if (currentFrame != value)
            {
                currentFrame = value;
                SetProperty(ref currentFrame, value);
            }
        }
    }

    private void StartVideo()
    {
        //CurrentFrame = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\Johannes\\Pictures\\Camera Roll\\asdf.bmp")) as BitmapSource;
        Capture = new VideoCapture();
        Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        //framerate of 10fps
        Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(async (object s, EventArgs a) =>
        {
            //draw the image obtained from camera
            using (Image<Bgr, byte> frame = Capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, byte>())
            {
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    CurrentFrame = ToBitmapSource(frame);
                }
            }
        });
        Timer.Start();
    }

    public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(IImage image)
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = source.GetHbitmap(); //obtain the Hbitmap
            BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ptr, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            DeleteObject(ptr); //release the HBitmap
            return bs;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete a GDI object
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("gdi32")]
    private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

}
```

A few thing for better understanding:

1. The ViewModelBase class incoorperates and handles the
   INotifyPropertyChange events.
2. Databinding is working! I have tested
       it, by assigning a bmp-file to `CurrentFrame` in the
       `StartVideo()`Method - and the image shows up in the GUI at runtime.
3. The `SetProperty()`Method fires every 1000ms as expected.
4. When I assigned a file to `CurrentFrame` to test the databinding, I
   saw that it seemed to be of type `BitmapImage`- maybe that's where the 
   problem lies?? However from the information I could gather,
   BitmapSource should work and show in WPF views...
5. The captured frame from the camera is not empty. I tried to write it
   directly to a image file and it shows the correct content as
   expected.

Edit:
For completeness here is also the responsible part of the view:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:CameraViewModel x:Key="vm" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
    <Image Source="{Binding CurrentFrame}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

Edit2: [Link to Github repository to view code](https://github.com/TheRealRolandDeschain/VisualDetection)

Comment: *When I assigned a file to CurrentFrame...* you mean then the image is visible?

Comment: @Clemens Yes, instead of using the captured frame from the camera, I loaded a bmp-file and assigned it to the `CurrentFrame`variable. Doing that the bmp-image was visible in the GUI.

Comment: And why is the Tick handler async? There doesn't seem to be any await.

Comment: Are you positively sure that Capture does return non-empty images, i.e. that are not fully transparent?

Comment: Yes, what I have also tested is to write the captured frame directly to a file - and it shows the correct content. -  I will edit this in the original question.

Comment: about the async actually not sure why it is there (as mention I took most of the code from the stated source)... but removing it doesn't really change anything.

Comment: You could also try to exclude CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap as potential source of an error. Replace that code by the other typical Bitmap-to-BitmapSource implementation, i.e. encode the Bitmap to a MemoryStream and decode a BitmapSource from it. You should have seen it here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Clemens Hmm, I will try that and report back here!

Comment: I tried a few different systems, for example also using the `Bitmap` property of the `Mat` directly, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your ViewModelBase class. How does it look like? Is the UI still showing the test file image even when the timer is started later?

Comment: [I pushed the project to a Github-Rep](https://github.com/TheRealRolandDeschain/VisualDetection) so the code can be viewed better there. I added a initialisation of the `CurrentFrame` variable with random colors to see if it shows up. It does, but doesn't change, so maybe the problem really lies with the ViewModelBase (which I just took from an older project). I'll give it a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not set

```
currentFrame = value;
```

before calling

```
SetProperty(ref currentFrame, value);
```

because the check

```
if (Object.Equals(storage, value)) return;
```

will always be true then.

Implement the property like this:

```
public BitmapSource CurrentFrame
{
    get { return currentFrame; }
    set { SetProperty(ref currentFrame, value); }
}
```

Comment: Oh man...so obvious and overlooked every time :D
Thanks a lot!!